# Understanding connection strings properly

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string, entity-framework-6

I've been messing with ASP.NET for a year or so but never paid much attention to connection strings.

Consider the following example scenario:

Project A <- references project b and calls ProjectB.Repository.GetCustomer()

Project B <- contains a repository with methods such as GetCustomer() etc.

In this scenario I'd assume that only Project B should contain a connection string, right?
After all projectA is only calling the repository of ProjectB and not the database itself.

But I assume I would need to hardcode the .mdf path in the connection string since it's being referenced by Project A?

Is this correctly understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this correctly understood?

No, there is no need/point in attaching the reference to mdf file in `projectA` since `projectA` just calling the function `GetCustomer()` in `projectB` which is responsible for querying the data and getting the customer list.

So, having the connection string in `projectB` only is enough.

Comment: Ahh I see.
So if projectA has an app.config and ProjctB has an app.config I would only need to include the connection string in the app.config of projectB?
But isn't variables such as DataDirectory going to be relative to ProjectA when it's the startup project? So if DataDirectory is used in projectB it will be relative to ProjectA?

Comment: @MichaelWaltz, that's correct. As a point of rule, if data access is needed only projectB then have the connection string only in projB.